# navegation bar with jquery not working with sticky position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple page with a div in the header that turns into a navbar when you scrolldown, it works great with `position:fixed` except it has an unwanted "fade left-to-right" animation when I scrolled down, however `position:sticky` has a wanted "fade center-to-sides" animation when scrolling down. The problem is that my code doesn't work with the sticky position as it should. Any ideas why`position:sticky` isnt' working?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if (Math.round($(window).scrollTop()) > 100) {
          $('header').addClass('scrolled');
          $('.toggle').addClass('scrolled-toggle')
          $('img').addClass('scrolled-toggle')
        } else {
          $('header').removeClass('scrolled');
          $('.toggle').removeClass('scrolled-toggle')
          $('img').removeClass('scrolled-toggle')
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
    body{
        width: 100vw;
        height:100vh;
        margin: 30px 0;
    }
    header{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: left;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        font-size: 1.4em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 120px;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 15px 20px;

    }
    section{
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 150px;
    }
    .toggle{
        display: none
    }
    img {
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .scrolled{
        position: sticky;
        background: rgba(168, 170, 51, 0.295);
        color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 15px 40px;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: 400;
        transition: .8s ease;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    .scrolled-toggle{
        display: inline;
        float: right;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
    <div style="height:150px">
    <header>
        this div turns into navbar
        <div class="toggle">
                menu
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
    <section>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio doloribus, architecto inventore veniam veritatis accusamus adipisci cumque voluptas cupiditate aliquam consequatur? Sed dolorem blanditiis reiciendis, eos assumenda porro perspiciatis labore?
    </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.scrolled {
    position:fixed;
}
```

Works!

> WebKit dropped sticky in 2013, Firefox in 2014, and now Blink in
>   (probably) 2016.

[Sticky usage stats](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)

If you really wanna use sticky, It seems there is a library that does the job [stickybits](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/stickybits)

Comment: Any way to change the transition with position:fixed to something resembling position:sticky?

Comment: @ahzep It seems there is a library that does the job [stickybits](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/stickybits)